# Bootstrap :Grid not working in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

The following is my grid structure for a site using bootstrap 3. It looks good in the desktop version but when I resize my window it does not go to mobile/tab view. Whats wrong here? On desktop I want them to take 1/6 of the row, and on mobile, 1/3.

```
<div class="row" id="features">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <div class="panel odd">
      <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
      <span>Treatments</span>
    </div>
  </div> <!--panel-->
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <div class="panel odd">
      <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
      <span>Treatments</span>
    </div>
  </div> <!--panel-->
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <div class="panel odd">
      <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
      <span>Treatments</span>
    </div>
  </div> <!--panel-->

  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <div class="panel odd">
      <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
      <span>Treatments</span>
    </div>
  </div> <!--panel-->

  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <div class="panel odd">
      <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
      <span>Treatments</span>
    </div>
  </div> <!--panel-->
</div><!--row-->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your goal?

In your code you design your structure same to your desktop structure.

Change the div classes in your inner container to something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
```

The number after the classes indicates the width inside the grid. The prefix `col-lg`, `col-md`, `col-sm`, `col-xs` indicates the different screen sizes (desktop, tablet, mobile)
More information you can find in the bootstraps grid section: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: did the trick for me . Thank u . But one point please if we dont need  to use col-lg-2 then whats the purpose of  this class ?  i mean if md classes work same then why lg class is required ?

Comment: `lg` and `md` is not the same. `lg` is for Large devices Desktops (≥1200px) and `md` for Medium devices Desktops (≥992px). See here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: Also, its wise to note, you don't need the lg-2 if md-2, since its medium "and up", you can eliminate that one in this example.

Answer (score 30):

Please check if you have included meta tags in your html head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. This is what causes an issue for a lot of people.

Comment: I already upvoted it. Your answer was at -1. I did see that your code block was not formatted correctly which is probably part of why you were downvoted. I already submitted an edit that is awaiting approval.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man, after spending an entire day with various permutations and combinations of all classes and sizes in bootstrap, this was the solution that finally worked. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't see any container, so I'm guessing you had none. The grid can malfunction if the this hierarchy is not respected: `container` => `row` => `col-??-##` => content. Also, if the panel odd class is for CSS, why don't you try pseudo-classes and to make it a little more compact, LESS for the `col` definitions.

Also, if you really want to experiment with mobile/tablet view, the Google Chrome Inspector is awesome for that and more accurate that just resizing the window.

This code works if you want it to look the same on any device, if you want them to take more space, consider changing from `col-??-2` to `col-??-4`, or for less space to: `col-??-1`.

```
<div class="container"> <!-- Or container-fluid, depending on your needs -->   
    <div class="row" id="features">
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
             <div class="panel odd">
                 <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
                 <span>Treatments</span>
             </div>
         </div> <!--panel-->
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
             <div class="panel odd">
                 <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
                 <span>Treatments</span>
             </div>
         </div> <!--panel-->
             <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                 <div class="panel odd">
                     <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
                     <span>Treatments</span>
             </div>
         </div> <!--panel-->

         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
             <div class="panel odd">
                 <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
                 <span>Treatments</span>
             </div>
         </div> <!--panel-->

         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
             <div class="panel odd">
                 <img src="images/treatment.png" alt="Treatments">
                 <span>Treatments</span>
             </div>
         </div> <!--panel-->
    </div><!--row-->
</div>
```